# How to Vue v-if equal or contains

Tags: javascript, vue.js, liquid

Can anyone please show me how to do this, I have a image with alt than contains alt="#color_blue" or alt="#color_orange", I call this data with Liquid as {{ media.alt }}

that I want to do is if the 'current_variant.alt' == {{ media.alt }} return true and also if the 'current_variant.alt' contain '#' return too true as well.

```html
<div v-if="current_variant.alt == '{{ media.alt }}' && current_variant.alt == '#'">

</div>
```

I don't know how to let **current_variant.alt** check if the **{{ media.alt }}** contains **#**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `string.includes` method to check if a string contains a particular character.

---

If you want to check if `current_variant.alt` equals `media.alt`:

```
current_variant.alt == '{{ media.alt }}'
```

---

If you want to check if `current_variant.alt` contains `'#'`:

```
current_variant.alt.includes('#')
```

---

If you want to check if `media.alt` contains `'#'`:

```
'{{ media.alt }}'.includes('#')
```

Comment: `String.prototype.contains` is deprecated for `String.prototype.includes`. You recommended `includes` in the first sentence, but used `contains` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

To check if current_variant.alt contain #, use Javascript "includes" =>  current_variant.alt.includes('#')

```
<div v-if="current_variant.alt == media.alt && current_variant.alt.includes('#')">    
</div>
```